# Insert a new row based on the maximum entries for an ID in another column using R

Tags: r

I got some data such as this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), adm = c("1", 
"2", "3", "Dead", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "4", "Dead"), 
status = c("dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "alive", "alive", 
"alive", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead", "dead")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I want something like this

```
structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
adm2 = c("1", "2", "3", "Dead", "1", "2", "3", "alive", "1", 
"2", "3", "4", "Dead"), status2 = c("dead", "dead", "dead", 
"dead", "alive", "alive", "alive", "alive", "dead", "dead", 
"dead", "dead", "dead")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

I want to consider the `id` column and if after maximum entries in column (`adm`) for each id, the status column is alive, then add the value from the status column into the adm column after their maximum value in the `adm` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming your starting data `df`, you could create a user defined function that evaluates your row insertion condition and map it to data grouped by `id`:

```
library(tidyverse)

appendcol <- function(df) {
  if (df$status[length(df$status)] == "alive") {
    newrow <- df[1,]
    newrow$adm <- "alive"
    return(bind_rows(df, newrow))
  } else {
    return(df)
  }
}

map_dfr(group_split(df, id), ~ appendcol(.))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
      id adm   status
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
 1     1 1     dead  
 2     1 2     dead  
 3     1 3     dead  
 4     1 Dead  dead  
 5     2 1     alive 
 6     2 2     alive 
 7     2 3     alive 
 8     2 alive alive 
 9     3 1     dead  
10     3 2     dead  
11     3 3     dead  
12     3 4     dead  
13     3 Dead  dead
```